# Python Pillow v2.6.0 paletted PNG (256) How to add an Alpha channel?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a numpy array that is written to an image, a RGB colormap added as a palette, and all that remains is a transparency channel (256 values) on top. I have tried converting to RGBA, LA, and other ways around it but, I cannot figure out how to add this multi-value channel on top as a palette.

Here is an example that I have that adds a single-value channel of transparency:

```
# data = numpy array 1624x3856
im = Image.fromarray(data)
im = im.convert('P')
# cmap is a 768-valued RGB array
im.putpalette(my_cmap)
im.save('filename.png', transparency=0)
```

The channel I want to save is as follows:

```
# len(alpha) = 256
alpha = [0,255,255,255...255,255,255]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does `print data.shape` show you?

Comment: `print data.shape` gives `(1624, 3856)`

and

`print im.size` gives `(3856, 1624)`

Comment: Numpy array for RGBA mode shall carry ( 4x8-bit pixels, [R,G,B]-true color with transparency mask ). Where did your code fail?

Comment: This code works, however, every time I try to put an alpha channel on top of the image, it doesn't like me. When I saved the image as above, it has a single-valued alpha channel of [0] rather than the one I'm wanting to save it as [0,255,255,255,...]

Comment: Your code does not "put an alpha channel on top of the image". Neither `data.shape` nor `im.size` match the `alpha.shape`

Comment: Correct. I was unsure on how to actually add this extra palette.

Comment: That exactly was posted yesterday in the Answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Prepare a correct RGBA format for working with an Alpha-channel

After preparing the RGB-part ( as an issue seen from the `data.shape` above )
your raster-image will have to get the corresponding Alpha-layer.

To do that, add a call to an instance method

**`Image.putalpha( anAlphaLAYER )`**

That adds / replaces the alpha-layer in your image. If the image does not have an alpha layer, it’s converted to <kbd>LA</kbd> or <kbd>RGBA</kbd>, so have the RGB-part ready before call to this method. The new layer ( `anAlphaLAYER` ) must be either <kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>1</kbd>.

So be sure to have `anAlphaLAYER.shape` matching your `im.size` ( X, Y ). Another possibility is to create alpha-layer from an integer value and modify it's cell-values ad-hoc.

Having done the full RGBA-format as early as in the numpy.array, the whole issue would not make you any troubles.

Comment: So, do you mean `Image.new('L', im.size, 255)`? I've tested this with the size and it is the same as the original image.

Comment: What do you mean by _Having done the full RGBA-format as early as in the numpy.array_?

Comment: ***RGBA-format as early as in the numpy*** reflects the fastest ever practice / approach, i.e. to manipulate [R,G,B]+[A]-layers straight in numpy array ( 1624, 3856, 4 ), as opposed to the slower PIL/Pillow pixel-by-pixel mode, and only finally convert/save into the requested fileformat. All computer vision tools & utilities work this way.

Comment: Ah. And I would create an image using the fromarray method and then convert to 'P' type and save? I wouldn't have to use the putpallete method nor the transparency=0 argument and still retain a paletted png with all channels still in tact?

Comment: Or you may use OpenCV2 tools to go faster for the same.

Comment: I will try that second method and let you know. Currently getting the putalpha method reviewed as well although I had to modify as the alpha layer was not a single valued image (i.e., I had to make 0's where I wanted them).

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple example on how to ensure a Pillow image is RGBA :

```
img = Image.open("SOME_RGB_IMAGE.png")

if img.mode == "RGB":
    a_channel = Image.new('L', img.size, 255)   # 'L' 8-bit pixels, black and white
    img.putalpha(a_channel)
```