# PIL Image.size returns the opposite width/height

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Using PIL to determine width and height of images

On a specific image (luckily only this one - but it is troubling) the width/height returning from image.size is the opposite.
The image:
http://storage.googleapis.com/cookila-533ebf752b9d1f7c1e8b4db3/IMG_0004.JPG

The code:

```
from PIL import Image
import urllib, cStringIO

file = cStringIO.StringIO(urllib.urlopen('http://storage.googleapis.com/cookila-533ebf752b9d1f7c1e8b4db3/IMG_0004.JPG').read())
im=Image.open(file)
print im.size
```

The result is - `(2592, 1936)`
should be the other way around

Comment: @mhawke - open the image in your browser and figure out the problem...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for this is that this image has [Exif `Orientation` metadata](http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2012/07/28/exif-orientation-handling-is-a-ghetto/) associated with it that will cause applications that respect that property to rotate it:

```
# identify -verbose IMG_0004.JPG | grep Orientation
  Orientation: RightTop
    exif:Orientation: 6
```

Compare with a regular image:

```
# identify -verbose iceland_pano.jpg | grep Orientation
  Orientation: TopLeft
    exif:Orientation: 1
```

So the image dimensions are actually landscape (more wide than high), but it will get rotated on display by browsers, image viewers etc.

Comment: Thanks @Lukas - so what do you recommend (assuming I want to behave like a browser/imageviewer etc.

Comment: Hmm, hard to say. Fortunately I never have been in a situation where I had to deal with this. I probably would check if the image has a non-conventional orientation, and if so, normalize it and [apply the rotation to the actual image data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606587/how-to-use-pil-to-resize-and-apply-rotation-exif-information-to-the-file).

Answer (score 2):

### A: This is a standard state.

Numpy arrays carry images ( from **`OpenCV2`** ) with another convention once inspected by **`data.shape`**, so does the PIL/Pillow **`Image.size`**

---

May review and validate as in >>> [Python Pillow v2.6.0 paletted PNG (256) How to add an Alpha channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26534148/3666197)

`print data.shape` gives `(1624, 3856)` and `print im.size` gives `(3856, 1624)`